# xcode project organisation

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a project MY_PROJECT. In xcode, I "see" all the classes under "Classes" folder but when I check on the filesystem I see the classes (.h / .m) beeing distributed in different folders:

- MY_PROJECT
- MY_PROJECT/Classes
- MY_PROJECT/...

How comes all the classes are not on the same Classes folder on the filesystem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XCode organises the the source files in "groups" that are independent of the file system. Because I find that this leads to a mess, I always create folders in the file system and use import with option "create groups for imported files and folder automatically". Thus groups and folders are in sync.

Comment: Actually these groups are not completely independent of the file system. You set a group's path (project relative, parent group relative, absolute, even SDK relative). This group then serves as an alias to the path. Files you create in this group are saved in the according directory of disk.

Comment: Ah, good to know. From my experience 2 years ago reorganising an XCode project was a pain. So I decided to create every new folder manually. New files in existing folders are then put into to the appropriate group folder correctly.